# Using AND operator in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I created a script to write the list of users in an OU to a spreadsheet and this works well. However now I wanted to script to write data for multiple OU's into the same spreadsheet but the '&&' operator does not seem to work. I tried using the OR '||" operator but that does not seem to work either. Any ideas?

```
function listAllUserRR() {

var sh = '1Or1yr9JtwsEvg97U1VjX4XNEZylxoVPwRzJXC6wZDKx';
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sh);
var sheet1 = sheet.getSheetByName('Google Users');
var sheet1range = sheet.getRange("A:F")
sheet1range.clear()
var data = [];// array to store values

data.push(['Email' ,'Firstname', 'Lastname', 'OU', 'Suspended', 'LastLoginTime']);// store headers
  var pageToken, page;
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({

      customer: 'C00ont7ej',
   query: "OrgUnitPath='/Brazil'" ||  "orgUnitPath='/Argentina'",

      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {


        var user = users[i];

        data.push([user.primaryEmail, user.name.givenName, user.name.familyName, user.orgUnitPath, user.suspended, user.lastLoginTime, ]);//store in an array of arrays (one for each row)

      }

    } else {
    Logger.log('No users found.');
       }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);

  sheet1.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
var dated = sheet.getRange("P1")
dated.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'dd-MMM-yyy'));


}
```

Comment: Why not just push two different times with two different queries?

Comment: I need the data to be appended into one sheet and I have many OU's hence that does not work for me. Need some other way around.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using '==' in your query?

Comment: '==' does not produce any output :(

Comment: you are having issues with basic javascript syntax. || will do nothing to the string. use a literal string "OR"

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
query: "OrgUnitPath='/Brazil'" ||  "orgUnitPath='/Argentina'",
```

because you use a javascript operator between two strings. Javascript will do:

if the first string is not falsey (not 0, null, undefined, false or empty), it will return the first string. Or if not, it will return the second string. Example:

```
var query = "OrgUnitPath='/Brazil'" || "orgUnitPath='/Argentina'";
console.log(query);
// Prints: OrgUnitPath='/Brazil'

var query = "" || "orgUnitPath='/Argentina'";
console.log(query);
// Prints: orgUnitPath='/Argentina'
```

This is definately not what you want. You just want something like this:

```
var query = "OrgUnitPath='/Brazil' OR orgUnitPath='/Argentina'";
console.log(query);
// Prints: OrgUnitPath='/Brazil' OR orgUnitPath='/Argentina'
```

Also notice that you are using `orgUnitPath`and `OrgUnitPath` (both uppercase and lowercase `o`). I don't know if the query is case sensitive, but it is good to be consistent anyways...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any indication that the Directory API lets you specify multiple OUs when searching for users:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users

Why not just split out the AdminDirectory lookup as a function that takes the OU name and the array and call it from a loop that passes each OU that you want and the array and then you can dump it all back into the spreadsheet.

```
function listAllUserRR() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.insertSheet(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'dd-MMM-yyy_HH:mm'));

  var data = [];// array to store values
  data.push(['Email' ,'Firstname', 'Lastname', 'OU', 'Suspended', 'LastLoginTime']);// store headers
  var orgUnitsArray = ["OrgUnitPath='/Brazil'", "orgUnitPath='/Argentina'"];
  for (var i=0; i < orgUnitsArray.length; i++) {

    getOrgUnitUsers(orgUnitsArray[i], data)

  }

  sheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}



function getOrgUnitUsers(orgUnit, userArray) {
  var pageToken, page;
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      customer: 'my_customer',
      query: orgUnit,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        userArray.push([user.primaryEmail, user.name.givenName, user.name.familyName, user.orgUnitPath, user.suspended, user.lastLoginTime, ]);//store in an array of arrays (one for each row)
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```